# Extension to Ubuntu Pro

Tags: upgrade

Translated:

To install the latest update I need Ubuntu Pro. Under "Your subscriptions" it tells me: "Free Personal Token - Machines 5 - Created 16 Jan 2024 - Expires Never".
Update still not possible; it continues to request "Enable Ubuntu Pro"

---

Original:

Zum Einspielen der neuesten Aktualisierung  benötige ich Ubuntu Pro. Unter "Your subscriptions" meldet er mir: "Free Personal Token -  Machines 5 - Created 16 Jan 2024 - Expires Never".
Aktualisierung trotzdem nicht möglich; er fordert weiterhin "Enable Ubuntu Pro"

Comment: Have you actually followed the instructions to *activate* Ubuntu Pro from within your subscription page?  If you *do not* put in the activation codes and activate your Ubuntu Pro subscription *on* the machine, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created an Ubuntu Pro token, but did not yet **activate** it on your machine. On the same "Your Subscription" page where you see the token info you quoted, you should also see the number of **active machines** using that token. If the number is 0, you need to activate the token on your machine.

Open the "Software & Updates" applet and go to "Ubuntu Pro" tab - this is the place where you have the option to actually enable Ubuntu Pro on your machine.